# UINavigationBar tint color does not update

Tags: ios, swift, colors, uinavigationbar

I am implementing a dark mode in my app. Here is my code (that I call when the screen is double tapped):

```
if darkMode == false {
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor(hexString: "#3A3A3A")
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()]
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
} else {
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.Default
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(hexString: "#FFFDF3")
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.blackColor()]
```

The only thing that updates is my status bar, but the navigation bar does update after I go into another view and return back to the main view. Why is that? Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. You can't change `appearance()` at runtime, but you can just do `navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()`

Answer (score 1):

I was just dealing with the same issue, turns out if you change `appearance()` proxy at runtime it doesn't have any effect. You need to change directly the properties of instances. So what you need to do is have subclassed `UINavigationBarController` with method where you set the colors and status bar appearance, for instance:

```
class ColorNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        setupForColor(UIFactory.sharedInstance.tintColor) //provides default color
    }

    func setupForColor(color: UIColor) {
        navigationBar.tintColor = color
        navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()]
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent

    }
}
```

Then when you double tap the screen:

```
if let colorNavigationController = self.navigationController as? ColorNavigationController {
    colorNavigationController.setupForColor(UIColor.redColor) // based on your current scheme
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me.  What am I doing wrong:  `func setupForColor(color: UIColor) {
        navigationBar.tintColor = color
        if darkMode == true {
        navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()]
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
        } else {
            navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor()]
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.Default
        }
    }`

Comment: And in my dark mode transform function:  `if let colorNavigationController = self.navigationController as? ColorNavigationController {
            if darkMode == true {
            colorNavigationController.setupForColor(UIColor(hexString: "3A3A3A")!)
            } else {
                colorNavigationController.setupForColor(UIColor(hexString: "#FFF8D3")!)
            }
        }`

Comment: Do you actually change the `darkMode` bool value as well?

Comment: Yes, it is included in the if statement in the original post, but I did not think it was needed to answer the question. (sorry for the late reply, MacBook had gone bonkers :/)

Comment: the code works for me, do you have the navigation controller class setup correctly in storyboard? Made sample project for you: https://github.com/libec/StackOverflow/tree/master/02-Navigation